# Computing $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{ikt}}{|e^{it}-e^{it_0}|^m}~\text{d}t$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $t_0\in\mathbb{C}$, and $m=1,3,5,\dots$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, integration, integral-transforms, quadrature

I am working on a project on accurate numerical quadrature where I need to compute the following integral in order to find my quadrature weights,

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}kt}}{\,\left\vert\,{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t} - {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t_{0}}}\,\,\right\vert^{\, m}\,}\,{\rm d}t,
$$

where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $t_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$, and $m = 1,3,5,\ldots$. The integrand experiences a singularity at $t=t_0$ and $t = \bar{t}_{0}$, and we may assume that $\text{Im}(t_0)\neq 0$. It may also be viewed as finding the Fourier coefficients of $1/|\rm e^{{\rm i}t} - \rm e^{{\rm i}t_{0}}|^m$.

What I am looking for is a closed-form expression of the integral that I hope is relatively cheap to evaluate for a given $t_0$. However, if someone is able to make any progress for e.g. only the case when $m=1$ and $k \geq 0$, it would be of much help.

---

You may also consider the integral rewritten into a contour integral over the unit circle $S$ by letting $\xi\left(t\right)={\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}$ and $\mu = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}t_0}$,

$$
\frac{1}{i}\oint_{S}\frac{\xi^{k - 1}}{\left\vert\xi-\mu\right\vert^{m}}\,{\rm d}\xi.
$$

I have not been able to make any significant progress on any of the two formulations.

Comment: If you write $t_0=\alpha+i\beta$, the denominator can be written in terms of  the Poisson kernel in the unit circle to the power $m/2$ and an explicit formula for the integrals follows at least when $m=2$.